# Option http_proxy not found

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to run this command

```
ffmpeg -http_proxy http://proxyip:1234 -i "http://videourl" -acodec libmp3lame -metadata title="test" -f mp3 -
```

But for some reason I keep getting this error

```
ffmpeg version git-2016-03-01-c3bb616 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-openssl --enable-gnutls
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 27.101 / 57. 27.101
  libavformat    57. 27.100 / 57. 27.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 38.100 /  6. 38.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Option http_proxy not found.
```

Any way I can force the install of the http_proxy? As the documentation shows it as a option.  Not sure what I'm missing

***Edit:***
When I posted this I had stripped down the logic and posted a url in place of what I was actually using which was the `pipe` function.  So inevitably the correct solution was what I posted.  Can not use `pipe` with `http_proxy`

Comment: Your ffmpeg looks new enough, and I don't see anything obviously odd about your command. I hardly ever request this, but perhaps adding `-loglevel debug` as a global option will show something of interest. Should say something like, `Reading option '-http_proxy' ... matched as AVOption 'http_proxy' with argument 'http://proxyip:1234'.`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  I posted a answer.  But it turns out that it was because of the ```pipe``` does not work with ```http_proxy```, didn't realize I actually posted what ended up being my solution by accident.

Comment: I see. I couldn't figure it out and wouldn't have ever guessed you were using a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that I was using `pipe` as the input.  That does not work apparently with the `http_proxy`, once I changed that to a URL it worked.

Comment: I don't quite understand the solution, could you elavorate by example?

Answer (score -1):

No, it has never shown `http_proxy` as an option. It's an *environment variable*:

```
export http_proxy="http://proxyip:1234"

ffmpeg -i "https://......"
```

Comment: The `-http_proxy` option was added to the FFmpeg http protocol in 2015 December. See commits [b4eb1f2](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=b4eb1f29ebddd60c41a2eb39f5af701e38e0d3fd) and [b9c46b5](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=b9c46b5242bf338f6e57bc6a4380e69be83c058c). (I've never tried it.)